# How to disable the warning "tensorflow:Method (on_train_batch_end) is slow compared to the batch update (). Check your callbacks"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, warnings, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to implement [Stochastic Weight Averaging (SWA)](https://github.com/timgaripov/swa) with tensorflow 2.0 in a keras style, so I need to update the SWA model weights every step. I have written a custom Callback to do this, but I get the warning every step. Here are some details:

My custom Callback:

```py
class CustomCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, valid_data, output_path, swa_alpha=0.99, eval_every=500, eval_batch=16, fold=None):
        self.valid_inputs = valid_data[0]
        self.valid_outputs = valid_data[1]
        self.eval_batch = eval_batch
        self.swa_alpha = swa_alpha
        self.fold = fold
        self.output_path = output_path
        self.rho_value = -1  # record the best rho for report
        self.eval_every = eval_every

    def on_train_begin(self, logs={}):
        self.swa_weights = self.model.get_weights()

    def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs={}):

        # update swa parameters
        alpha = min(1 - 1 / (batch + 1), self.swa_alpha)
        current_weights = self.model.get_weights()
        for i, layer in enumerate(self.model.layers):
            self.swa_weights[i] = alpha * self.swa_weights[i] + (1 - alpha) * current_weights[i]

        # validation
        if batch > 0 and batch % self.eval_every == 0:
            # do validation
            val_pred = self.model.predict(self.valid_inputs, batch_size=self.eval_batch)
            rho_val = compute_spearmanr(self.valid_outputs, val_pred)  # the metric

            # set the swa parameters and do validation
            self.model.set_weights(self.swa_weights)
            swa_val_pred = self.model.predict(self.valid_inputs, batch_size=self.eval_batch)
            swa_rho_val = compute_spearmanr(self.valid_outputs, swa_val_pred)

            # reset the original parameters
            self.model.set_weights(current_weights)

            # check whether to save model and update best rho value
            if rho_val > self.rho_value:
                self.rho_value = rho_val
                self.model.save_weights(f'{self.output_path}/fold-{fold}-best.h5')

        del current_weights
        gc.collect()
```

The output is something like this:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Method (on_train_batch_end) is slow compared to the batch update (11.428264). Check your callbacks.
WARNING:tensorflow:Method (on_train_batch_end) is slow compared to the batch update (11.464315). Check your callbacks.
WARNING:tensorflow:Method (on_train_batch_end) is slow compared to the batch update (11.502968). Check your callbacks.
WARNING:tensorflow:Method (on_train_batch_end) is slow compared to the batch update (11.518413). Check your callbacks.
```

I am getting the warning every step, which means without running the validation code, the code for updating SWA params (`self.model.get_weights()` and the following `for` loop) is slow enough.

I understand that updating the parameters is very slow because `model.get_weights()` and `model.set_weights()` will both do a deep copy of params (a new list of new numpy ndarray according to my experiment).

I think there is nothing wrong with my implementation of SWA (please let me know if there is any bug), so I just want to disable the warning.

What I have tried:

1. Adding the code `os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "2"` and `os.environ["TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL"] = "3"` to disable WARNING.
2. Setting `verbose` to `2` and `0` in `model.fit()`, i.e. `model.fit(..., verbose=2, ...)` and  `model.fit(..., verbose=0, ...)`

Both do no work.

Any idea? Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a very satisfying answer, but TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL not working is a known issue: [TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL does not work with TF2.0 dev20190820](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/31870).

I was able to reproduce your issue on `tensorflow==2.1.0-rc1` with a toy example here:

```
import os
import time
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = "2"
import tensorflow as tf
tf.get_logger().setLevel("WARNING")
tf.autograph.set_verbosity(2)

print(tf.__version__)

mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
  tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
  tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')
])

class CustomCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):

  def on_train_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
    time.sleep(3)

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1, callbacks=[CustomCallback()])
```

```
2.1.0
Downloading data from https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/tf-keras-datasets/mnist.npz
11493376/11490434 [==============================] - 31s 3us/step
Train on 60000 samples
WARNING:tensorflow:Method (on_train_batch_end) is slow compared to the batch update (3.002797). Check your callbacks.
   32/60000 [..............................] - ETA: 1:57:38 - loss: 2.4674 - accuracy: 0.0938WARNING:tensorflow:Method (on_train_batch_end) is slow compared to the batch update (3.002938). Check your callbacks.
...
```

None of the standard suggestions (`os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL']`, `tf.get_logger().setLevel("WARNING")` or `tf.autograph.set_verbosity(2)`) work and I suspect you'll have to wait until the issue above is resolved.

Comment: Have you tried tf.get_logger().setLevel("ERROR") instead of warning (actually you want hide warning or not)? With tf 2.20 nightly it is working.